# JQuery Fade Out/Hide Previous DIVS

Tags: jquery, hidden, fadeout

I'm trying to create a simple page where 3 divs overlap one another with various content. Within each DIV is an image (a NEXT button) that should fade out the initially shown DIV, and FadeIn the second DIV. Within that 2nd DIV, is another NEXT button to FadeOut DIV 2 and FadeIn DIV 3.

I'm having problems hiding the previously shown DIV, and all 3 end up showing all their content on top of one another.

Please help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<style>
div {
width:80px; 
display:none;
height:80px; 
z-index : 1;
position: fixed; 
top: 20px; 
left: 20px; 
}

div#one { background:#f00; }
div#two { background:#0f0; }
div#three { background:#00f; }


form {
    border: thick solid #1D4600;
        height: 500px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <div id="one" style="display:inline !important">
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
<img src="test.gif" width="95" height="72" class="nextlink"></div>

    <div id="two"><a href="#">link2</a>
<img src="test.gif" width="95" height="72" class="nextlink">
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
</div>

    <div id="three">Other text</div>
</form>

<script>
  $("img.nextlink").click(function(event) {
  $("div:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
 });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?
The code could used cleaned up but this should get you off to a good start

```
$("div:first").show();

$("img.nextlink").click(function(event) {
   $(this).parent().hide();
    if ($(this).parent().next("div").length == 0) {
        $("#one").fadeIn("slow");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parent().next("div").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CK9H8/

Comment: Perfect, thank you! That's essentially what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: You're welcome! Like i said, the code could probably be cleaned up - and made better for your SPECIFIC need, however I hope this sample gets you to better refined code for your specific usage!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work if there's a <table> within the DIV. Any idea why?

Comment: It also seems to fail it there are other DIVs as part of the main DIV.

Comment: can you update your code... i had built it based upon the original code sample which did not contain a table.

Comment: If you are adding a table its probably making $(this).parent() not work as its pulling the parent being a table instead the wrapping div.